# "Buttery" fragment animations in "pre-butter" Android

Tags: android, performance, animation, android-fragments

I'm using Google's compat lib to enable fragments in my app (Target SDK 16, Min SDK 8) for devices running on 2.2+. From a functional point of view this runs all fine, but the performance of the view animations that are set up via

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.setCustomAnimations(inTransition, outTransition, popInTransition, popOutTransition);
```

where `inTransition` is a simple translation like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="@integer/animation_duration" />
</set>
```

and `outTransition` is a fade animation like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="@integer/animation_duration" />
</set>
```

is just plain awful on my Galaxy S2 (4.0.3), i.e. for an animation that lasts about 350ms I'd say approx. half of the frames are dropped. I noticed that the performance gets a little (but not much) better if I disable the fade out, but then of course the complete effect of the animation is gone, because the origin fragment turns black instantly. I also tried a release version of the code, but the performance did not improve either.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make fragment animations smoother?

Comment: What are you animating, specifically? Did you disable hardware acceleration for some reason? What is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: Hardware Acceleration was the right hint! I cannot believe that I oversaw that. Now it runs smooth as it should on 4.0 and beyond - thanks a bunch!
Btw: Add a regular answer, so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first thing I'd recommend is enable hardware acceleration in the Manifest.  This will only be enabled on devices with API 3.0+, but will **significantly** improve performance.  With API 11 (3.0) and up, you can also take advantage of [View LayerTypes.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayerType%28int,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)  Set whatever you're animating to `LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE` then set it back to `LAYER_TYPE_SOFTARE` or `LAYER_TYPE_NONE` upon completion.

Pre-honeycomb it becomes far more difficult.  You don't have hardware acceleration at all.  You may be better off checking `if(api < 11) *use this animation* else *use this animation*`.  Sliding animations tend to work fairly smooth.  Alpha animations are a burden on the CPU, especially when views have many layers. Apply any animation on the top-most parent view you can get away with (you're animating entire fragments so it's already happening).

Comment: if I set hardware acceleration in the application, do I have to set `LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE` on the view I'm animating? I have hardware acceleration turned on and I still experience very awful animations in Android 4.1.2

Comment: I think somewhere it says you don't, but I haven't found the case.  I set the layer type to hardware on the top-most parent view that I'm animating.  It essentially flattens that View and animates the parent view and all its children at once.  Once it's done animating, I set the layer type to `NONE` to take it out of hardware memory.

Comment: Can you post an example for changing layer type on fragment transaction animations? I set `ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right)` on the fragment transaction and tried to override `onCreateAnimation` of the `Fragment` and did `getView().setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)` on animation start and `getView().setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);` on animation end, however `onCreateAnimation` is never called

Comment: I haven't tried it, but from what I can tell by this blog post: http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2012/06/fragment-transactions-reference.html
The two methods work in separate ways.  So you use one or the other but not both.  In this case, override the method `onCreateAnimation`, create your animation based on enter or exit, then return that.  If you use `setCustomAnimations`, then it will ignore the animations returned in `onCreateAnimation`. The rest should work the same way.

Comment: That's a shame. I `Fragment` shouldn't be directly attached to it's enter/exit animations. Sometimes I use the same `Fragment` with enter/exit animations and sometimes not. If it didn't ignore `setCustomAnimations` this would be the perfect solution. I will try what you said, Thanks.

Comment: Is there any problem to set `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)` in `onCreateView` and don't set it back to `View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE`?

Comment: There are certain drawing operations that down work when the view is in a Hardware layer. Those operations will most likely crash your app or at best be completely ignored. Also, it puts the view inside hardware memory, so it could cause problems if your app is very animation heavy and you're putting many views inside the hardware.  Aside from that, you could get away with it as long as your remember to take the view out of hardware memory when the fragment is destroyed.